# Etherscan verification purpose

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

What is the purpose of the smart contract code Etherscan verification?

Is it meant to verify ownership, or malicious lines of code, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It verifies that the bytecode of the smart contract which is stored in the Ethereum network corresponds to the Solidity code initially available only to the smart contract developer.

Etherescan will compile the Solidity code and check that the resulting bytecode exactly matches the bytecode stored in the Ethereum network. People reading the smart contract know that the code is what actually will be executed when they call the smart contract.

---

Interestingly, anyone can submit the Solidity code **with their comments** for any contract. If they can do it before the owners do, then they managed to publish the Solidity code on Etherscan with arbitrary comments. The owners will probably have to contact Etherscan's support to fix it.

Although [changing comments changes the swarm hash appended to the bytecode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41540/why-does-changing-comments-in-the-smart-code-change-its-bytecode), Etherscan ignores it during verification https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/456#issuecomment-370133955

Comment: Not any more. Not etherscan checks it.

Answer (score 3):

From https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/16/verifying-contract-source-code/:

> The power of smart contracts is that they’re “trustless.” Once deployed, a smart contract is immutable and tamper-proof. It is guaranteed to execute exactly the code that was written. That guarantee, however, is only meaningful if you know what code is being executed.
>
> Everything on the blockchain is public, including smart contracts’ bytecode, but bytecode is low-level and quite difficult to understand. The source code, written in Solidity, is much more useful. If you want other people to trust your smart contracts, you should publish the source code, and before you interact with someone else’s smart contract, you should examine their source code.