# Why does changing comments in the smart contract change its bytecode?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

Why are these 2 smart contracts, which differ only in the comments, result in different bytecode:

1st

```
pragma solidity 0.4.20;

contract Test {

  // test
  function test() pure public {

  }
}
```

2nd

```
pragma solidity 0.4.20;

contract Test {

  // test2
  function test() pure public {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Solidity compiler appends the metadata file hash at the end of the bytecode http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/metadata.html

Metadata file is a json file that contains hashes of source files so changing comments changes the metadata file hash.

Comment: Very interesting! Please mark your own answer as the correct answer :)

Comment: It's a time lock imposed to give other people time to answer the question :-) There were also arguments that it prevents the OP from gaming the system, although I'm not really sure how they would given there's no rep involved...

Comment: Just noticed this today.  Great question and great answer!