# Different bytecode when compiling from both solc-js and Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, bytecode, compilation, solcjs

Currently, I'm trying to get the bytecode from this contract code for example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GetSet {
  uint256 private total;
  mapping(address => uint256) private numbers;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private heavyArr;

  function getTotal() external view returns (uint256) {
    return total;
  }

  function setNumber(uint256 _num) external returns (bool) {
    total = total - numbers[msg.sender] + _num;
    numbers[msg.sender] = _num;
    return true;
  }

  function setHeavy() external returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      heavyArr[i] = heavyArr[i] + 1;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function getNumber(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
    return numbers[_user];
  }
}
```

both Complitation have `optimization enabled` with `counts of 200` and using `version v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7`

Here is how I used solc-js for compile:

```
  const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'GetSet.sol': {
        content: contractCode,
      },
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['*'],
        },
      },
      optimizer: {
        // disabled by default
        enabled: true,
        // Optimize for how many times you intend to run the code.
        // Lower values will optimize more for initial deployment cost, higher values will optimize more for high-frequency usage.
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  };
  solc.loadRemoteVersion('v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7', function (err, solcSnapshot) {
    // NOTE: Use `solcSnapshot` here with the same interface `solc` has
    const output = JSON.parse(solcSnapshot.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

    // `output` here contains the JSON output as specified in the documentation
    for (const contractName in output.contracts['GetSet.sol']) {
      console.log(
        output.contracts['GetSet.sol'][contractName].evm.bytecode.object
      );
    }
  });
```

and this is on remix IDE:

[image]

as you can see the settings are the same, I got the result from both as following:

SOLC-JS:

> 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

REMIX IDE:

> 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

the 2 bytecode are different at the end

[image]

What am I missing, I double check all the settings even metadatas are the same but I don't get why they are different

```
{
  "compiler": {
    "version": "0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7"
  },
  "language": "Solidity",
  "output": {
    "abi": [
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_user",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "getNumber",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getTotal",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "setHeavy",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "_num",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "setNumber",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ],
    "devdoc": {
      "kind": "dev",
      "methods": {},
      "version": 1
    },
    "userdoc": {
      "kind": "user",
      "methods": {},
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "compilationTarget": {
      "GetSet.sol": "GetSet"
    },
    "evmVersion": "london",
    "libraries": {},
    "metadata": {
      "bytecodeHash": "ipfs"
    },
    "optimizer": {
      "enabled": true,
      "runs": 200
    },
    "remappings": []
  },
  "sources": {
    "GetSet.sol": {
      "keccak256": "0xbe599f5bcbd0c9cd18e7aec3a5bdf55709bfe578823a7943d3f8a084959967f6",
      "license": "MIT",
      "urls": [
        "bzz-raw://d6f14d23add195e111ce54578e8332bf9d49654cc5a1092bd12a9f1f7664aed5",
        "dweb:/ipfs/QmSrXqqsPzgGxYNSnBz2f5xfKpXi7sXiJr2Fva9L8gsuKY"
      ]
    }
  },
  "version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a spacing issue or comments...don't know if remix adds anything, but looks like it's the metadata that's different and not the actual logic:  [Why does changing comments in the smart contract change its bytecode?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41540/why-does-changing-comments-in-the-smart-contract-change-its-bytecode)

Comment: is there any way how to differ metadata from logic in bytecode?

Comment: metadata is last 32 bytes (hash of contract)